# Why are my friends flying over Norway, Sweden and Denmark from Manchester to Vancouver?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-path

I'll start off by letting you all know that I am 100% blind, so I won't be able to read a map.

My friend Hudson came over to Canada with her friends last year, September 1 or August 31, 2016.

She likes to check where she's at once in a while when flying. She said it was an Air Transat Airbus 330-200. She doesn't remember the flight number, but it was probably TSC-285 or TSC-255.

Anyway, when she flew from Manchester (EGCC) to Vancouver (CYVR), she said "(laughs), Ann was out like a light when we flew over the Scandinavian countries." How on earth does this work?  I may be blind, but I do know that Vancouver is southwest of Manchester, and the Scandinavian countries are northeast of Manchester.

My question is, why would they fly over Norway, Sweden and Denmark when that is the opposite way to Vancouver? I'd love for an explanation please.

Note:

If you explain the route i.e. "she went north over x, then headed west and flew over by y" that would help, though it's not a requirement.  It is guessing after all considering she may have taken off northeast or southeast from EGCC.

Comment: Yes she said they flew over the scandinavian countries while going form Manchester to Vancouver.

Comment: Are you sure she isn't including Iceland in that bin of "Scandanavian countries", or the fact that Greenland is run by Denmark?

Comment: Alls she said was the Scandanavian countries.  and why would she go over greenland or iceland? Vancouver is southwest of manchester, at around 49 degrees North lat while Manchester is about 53 degrees North.

Comment: As to Greenland & Iceland -- the answer has to do with great circles as we live on a round planet, not a flat pancake :)

Comment: She may have been referring to greenland or Iceland, still, would there be a doable route to Vancouver flying over Norway, Sweden or Denmark? and then there's still the track southwest from greenland, accross Canada and to the west coast.  (sorry if i'm being an idiot)

Comment: I edited the question so it gives you Hudson's exact words. (laughs) "Ann was out like a light when we flew over the Scandinavian countries"

Comment: She also said "'ad to wake the others up when we were over Alaska" so I knew she flew over Alaska, which is still too far north. or maybe I'm missing something. Perhaps if you kinda ran through the route i.e. she would have went norh twards x, then east twards Y).  I'm blind and can't read a map online, but doing something like (north twards x and east twards Y) wouldhelp me understand the great circle route she took better.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a while ago, since Air Transat only seems to fly Manchester-Vancouver in the summer? If it was within the last seven days, the flight number would be invaluable as we can then look on flightradar24.com to see the exact route the plane took.

Comment: @David Richerby it was like August 31 or September 1, 2016 and Hud saw her old flight record and she said it was air transat flight 285

Comment: @TheCat-alyst Ok -- that probably pins it down to just a couple of possible flights. It's possible somebody has a subscription to one of the flight-tracking sites that allows them to see flights from more than a week ago, so they'd be able to see exactly where the plane went.

Comment: @David Richerby I wish I had a subscription to flightaware or something like that.  I know that it was either august 31, 2016 or September 1, 2016 because Hud and the girls arrived in my home town the next day due to having to stay overnigh tin Vancouver.  Yeah, I think it may be tsc285, or at least the air transat flight from Manchester to Vancouver on either August 31, 2016  or September 1, 2016.  that should help.

Comment: Could also have been [TSC 255](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/TSC255/history/20161017/1030ZZ/EGCC/CYVR). This flight appears representative of the MAN-YVR seasonal route. It did indeed go over Iceland, then Greenland, then Nunavut, Alberta, etc. The route was EGCC 5500N/11800W MERYT BOOTH LIONN1 CYVR. This is basically a straight (great circle) line from Manchester to Alberta.

Comment: @Michael Hampton ah, gotcha.  strange that HUdson said she was over the Scandinavian countries when Ann fell asleep.  Unless she was going by the fact that the vikings colonised those places, though that is srange. thanks though, you are amazing.

Comment: Well, technically Greenland is still a (largely autonomous) part of Denmark. So it's kind of sort of true... She might also have been mistaken.

Comment: @Michael Hampton fair point.  it's kinda fascenating to learn just where one would fly over when going somewhere, I'm hoping to go to Manchester myself in the near future.  Also had i not have lost my sight hwen I was 7, I'd probibly be training to be a commercial pilot right now, because I've always loved commercial aviation.

Comment: Sounds like you know more about geography than your sighted friends do.

Comment: @Tyler Durden i did my best to pay attention in geography class back in 2001. pluss I love traveling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]
(gcmap.com)

Above is the shortest route, it's called a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) route. This is what airlines try to follow as much as possible.

The possibilities:

1. They've mistaken the icy parts of Greenland and northern Canada for the Scandinavian countries<sup>1</sup>
2. They've mistaken the western Scottish [fjords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fjord) for Scandinavian fjords
3. They need new maps :)

---

On a great circle route, like a taut thread over a ball, the bearing changes. Roughly it'll be something like this:

Initial heading of NW for 1,000 nautical miles, WNW for another 1,000, then West for 2,700. That's a very rough visualization, because again along the route the heading changes, just like the thread.

The route takes you along the western coast of Scotland, across the Atlantic, passing over Iceland, then Greenland, then Canada, where Vancouver is.

---

<sup>1</sup> Denmark, Norway, and Sweden compose Scandinavia according to the normal definition.

Comment: thanks.  I know someone above theorized that Hudson could be referring to Greenland as a "scandinavian country".  she is a viking fanatic. maybe she needed to clairify her terminology. thanks.

Comment: I wonder if this is also to do with Polar routes? Wikipedia says that some trans-continental flights use the arctic circle for some routes.

Comment: @TheCat-alyst, yes, that's the same thing. The Earth is a sphere, not a cylinder. On a sphere, you get shortest path when you intersect it with a plane that passes the two points and the centre. That means that when you are connecting two points on the north hemisphere, the route is going to take you further north and on south hemisphere it's going to take you further south. The effect is more pronounced when the points are further apart, so for points at about opposite longitudes (e.g. New York-Beijing) it will take you almost over the pole.

Comment: Also, the flight might have diverted further north to avoid the strong west wind of the [Jet stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_stream). That would mean departing about north, following coast of Norway for a while before turning north-west over Atlantic.

Comment: @JanHudec But "about north" from Manchester goes nowhere near Norway. To reach Norway, you'd have to fly more than 600km east of due north.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, OK, north-north-east. There are no airways directly north of Great Britain, so if you don't want to join the North Atlantic Track system yet due to position of Jet stream, you might have to fly along the coast of Norway to get to suitable NAT entry point.

Comment: @Jan Hudec  so is it possible that Hudson could also have referred to that when she said that Ann fell asleep  over the scandinavian countries? or is it as ymb1 said and Hud mistook some of the areas of Scotland, Greenland or Northern Canada for Norway?

Comment: @TheCat-alyst, I don't think we can tell for sure. Perhaps if we knew the exact date and there was somebody around with good enough Flightradar24 plan they could find the actual track. Otherwise it's just a guess.

Comment: @Jan Hudec It was eithe rSeptember 1 or August 31, 2016, and the flight number is either tsc285 or tsc255, EGCC to CYVR.

Comment: @TheCat-alyst, I edited them into the question for you. I don't have FR24 subscription myself, but if there is somebody around with the gold one, they might be able to find it.

Comment: @Jan Hudec thanks.  I only wish I had that info sooner.

Comment: https://flightaware.com/live/flight/TSC284/history/20170623/0130ZZ/CYVR/EGCC can someone please describe where this flight went? which areas it went over? thanks.