# Is there a way to get descriptions of great circle routes?

Tags: navigation, flight-path

Given that I am blind and love to know where I'm flying over, is there a online service that describes a great circle route in text form? e.g. in a format like this:

> A great circle from CYVR to LTBA goes NNE over British Columbia,
>   Alberta, Northwest Territories and Nunavut, passing over Arctic bay in
>   the northernmost part of Baffin Island. Then across the middle of
>   Greenland, crossing the Atlantic to Norway then Sweden, passing abut
>   30 miles west of Stockholm. Then across the Baltic Sea and over the
>   Kaliningrad Oblast, which is the small exclave of Russia that sits
>   between Poland and Lithuania. Then across eastern Poland, western
>   Ukraine, Romania, the very corner of Bulgaria, across the very western
>   edge of the Black Sea and arrives in Istanbul from NNW.

(thanks to @TomMcW who left this in my previous question).

This way I can stop asking these great circle questions here.

Comment: How do you usually read maps ?

Comment: Have you tried using Google Earth to draw the great circle and make your own notes? The issue in any case is that the routes can vary significantly from the great circle to take advantage of winds. I've seen mid-course variations of over 1500 miles on long overseas flights.

Comment: I'm blind and i can't use google earth maps.  unless there's a tactile map that exists I can't read it.  and Hudson isn't always around to describe it to me, and I shouldn't have to always rely upon her.

Comment: @TheCat-alyst I have seen globes of earth that have the topography of the land on the surface that allows you actually feel the topography. You could identify the start and stop location on the globe and then trace with you hand and fingers a straight line and feel the continents and oceans and mountain ranges...etc. You may want more detail than this, but it could be very insightful. A physical globe is the best way for me personally to visualize great circle routes. Granted, its not very convenient to carry around.

Comment: I've seen references in two of your questions and you have me quite curious now. Who or what is Hudson (if I'm not being too personal)? You speak of "her" as though she's a friend, yet I get the feeling it is some sort of a device, instead.

Comment: I was wondering who, or what Hudson is too. I can't help but think of Tom Hanks' soccer ball, Wilson :)

Comment: @TomMcW and FreeMan Hudson is a friend of mine, she's originally from Manchester. She was the Hudson I referred to in my question regarding the flight between Manchester and Vancouver. She's good at trackign where we fly whe we travl together because her dream is to be a pilot herself.

Comment: @TheCat-alyst For your information, the Earth is NOT a perfect sphere.   It is like an old, dented baseball, hit hundreds and hundreds of times. Most globes (all that I know of) are spheres.  Most calculations use the Haversine formula, which treats the Earth like a sphere.  If you are talking military grade precision, you cannot use this approximation, favoring other much more complex math (there's half a dozen solutions, more or less complex and precise).  PS: 2D maps (Mercator maps) are NOT in proportion: Europe is displayed at a closer zoom level than other regions, like South America.

Comment: @tony gil Basically I am looknig for descriptions of where I would fly over, it doesn't have to be ultra precise, basically more like the description i cited above, though exact distances and directions aren't required. also keep in mind I'm bilnd and tactile globes don't show countries, they only show the topographical views.

Comment: @TheCat-alyst I pretty much thought so.  On the other hand, I am sure that my graphic explanation will give you a better idea ofwhat this lump of rock of ours occupies space.  As for Mercator distortions, the topography of Europe is easily identified. STEP 1: Find Africa.  STEP 2: Find the Mediterranean Sea above Africa.  Step 3: Everything North of that, basically constitutes Western Europe, the Balkans (you'll find a mountain ridge there, which is sort of the eastern boundary of Europe.  Bear in mind that Europe is not separate from Asia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Thread

In your [Manchester to Vancouver](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35564) question, I wrote that a great circle is like a taut thread on a ball.

If you have a tactile (Braille) globe, get two pins and a thread. Place the pins on the departure and arrival cities, and wrap the thread around the pins so that the thread is taut. You can then follow along with your finger.

#### Coordinates

Another method is to go to [Route Finder](http://rfinder.asalink.net/free/) website.

Enter the departure and arrival airports ICAO codes (you can get them from Wikipedia). And plot the flight plan.

The generated flight plan will be close enough to a great circle. The waypoints will be listed by their latitude and longitude. The distance and track (heading) for each leg will also be listed.

Comment: Another potential tool is WolframAlpha. I tried "[what countries are on the great circle from Amsterdam to Athens](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+countries+are+on+the+great+circle+from+Amsterdam+to+Athens)" to no avail, but this could be investigated further.

Comment: You could try [gis.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com) too, there may be a generic, non-aviation approach to this